# Greg's SGcraft stargate redstone issues

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-redstone

I am using Greg's SGcraft for minecraft 1.7.10, and the stargate is supposed to output a redstone signal when active. It does that, but when the gate turns off, the repeater stays active unless I break it. help?

Comment: We can't help you with issues of mods. Report this error to the mod author, please.